# Why is Epsilon-induction well founded?

Tags: set-theory

I understand that for a relation to be well founded, it must have a least element (e.g. $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ ) is well founded because there is no natural number smaller than $1$.

I came across the idea of epsilon induction recently, where $y \in x$ is a well founded relation.

Why is this well founded? What does it mean to be a least element in this case?

Answer (score 5):

To say that an irreflexive relation $\lt$ is well-founded does **not** mean that it has a least element. What it means is that **every nonempty set** has at least one **minimal** element. A minimal element of a set $X$ is an element $x\in X$ such that there is no $y\in X$ with $y\lt x.$ It is not necessarily the least element of $X;$ a set may have many minimal elements. In set theory, the [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) (aka Axiom of Foundation, aka Mirimanoff's Axiom) says that the set-membership relation $\in$ is well-founded.

Answer (score 1):

In ZF set theory, one of the axioms states that $\in$ is well-founded. That's the only reason it works: we've said that things for which it doesn't work are not sets, and we refuse to work with them.

In that case, *a minimal* (not "the least") element of a set $x$ is a $y\in x$ such that for any $z\in x$ we have $z\notin y$. If $x$ is non-empty, then such a $y$ always exists according to the above mentioned axiom.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the membership relation on sets well-founded?  This is not an arbitrary decision: it's how the issue raised by Russell's paradox is resolved, while letting the mathematical universe be as large as it can be (but hopefully no larger).

So we'll take a side path in the history of mathematics through Russell's paradox and type theory, to see how ZF, including the axiom of foundation, arose.

Russell's paradox showed that one cannot consistently regard sets as merely arbitrary properties. Specifically, Russell discovered that the following, seemingly natural approach (now known as "naive set theory") results in a contradiction:

1. We have a universe of all sets, given in advance. (This isn't meant to imply that we know what every set is, of course, but, whatever the universe is, it's fixed.)
2. For any property $P,$ we can carve out, from the universe of all sets, the set $\lbrace x \mid P(x)\rbrace,$ which must be one of the sets that's already in the universe.

The paradox is that if you carve out the set $W=\lbrace x \mid x \not\in x\rbrace,$ you can see that $W\in W \iff W \not \in W,$ which is a contradiction.

This problem arises from the very idea that the universe of sets is given in advance and that we can carve out any piece of this universe to form a set, and then the set that we carved out must be one of the sets that's already in the universe.  In other words, when we define $\lbrace x \mid P(x)\rbrace,$ we're not creating a new set; we're simply identifying a set that already exists.  But then property $P$ is either true of this set or it's not, and this leads to Russell's paradox.

There's a competing view of what a set is, however: In this view, sets are *constructed* one step at a time, not carved out of a pre-existing universe of all sets.  So now a set is formed as a collection of objects that you already know about.  The mathematical universe is constructed in steps or stages, and instead of looking at $\lbrace x \mid P(x) \rbrace,$ at any stage $s,$ you can only construct $\lbrace x \mid P(x)\text{ holds, and }x\text{ was already constructed before stage }s\rbrace.$  (This means that there isn't even the option for a set to belong to itself, because, when you're constructing a set, it's not one of the objects that's already available, and those already-constructed objects are the ones that you're carving this new set out of).

This leads to type theory, which corresponds closely to how people often actually work in mathematics.  We have, for example, real numbers, which are one type of object (type $0$ objects), sets of real numbers, which are another type of object (type $1$ objects), collections of sets of real numbers (type $2$ objects), etc.

Notice that now we can't carve out *all* sets with a given property, because every set has to be constructed at some stage, and all of its members come from the previous stage.  So no set can encompass members from all stages.

This is actually good enough to do most of ordinary mathematics, but there are three ways that it's not satisfactory:

1. Why can't we have heterogeneous sets which contain elements of more than one type (for example, a set like $\lbrace 5, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace \rbrace,$ which contains both a type 0 object and a type 1 object)?
2. Where do the type $0$ objects (numbers, or whatever) come from?
3. What does the "etc." mean at the end of the type-based construction of sets above?  How many stages are there?

Issue 1 is easy to address: At each stage, allow a set to be constructed from objects at *any* earlier stage, not just the immediately preceding stage.  So $\lbrace 5, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace \rbrace$ would be a type-$2$ object, whose elements are a type $0$ object and a type $1$ object.

Issue 2 is also easy to address: In principle, you can start with any predetermined objects you want as type-$0$ objects.  These are called $urelements,$ and they're not sets, so they have no members themselves.  In practice, however, we normally start with no urelements at all, because it turns out, somewhat surprisingly, that we don't need them — we can construct every mathematical pattern or structure we need without urelements. (How do we get something out of nothing? After all, at stage $0,$ we have no objects at all.  But at stage $1,$ we get $\emptyset.$ At stage 2, we add $\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace.$  At stage 3, we add $\lbrace \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace \rbrace$ and $\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace \rbrace,$ and so on.  Amazingly enough, this will end up giving us everything we need, as we make our way up through the stages.)

Issue 3, how many stages there are, is a lot trickier and actually can't be fully resolved — no matter how many stages you have, there's always the possibility that you could go even farther.  But there are natural stopping points where you *could* be done.

So you construct the type-$n$ objects for each natural number $n,$ as above.  But that clearly isn't enough — you don't have any infinite sets yet.  So we'll keep on going. After all, the idea is that at any point in the process, we should be able to go on further and carve out new sets from any already-constructed sets.  For any set $x$ constructed at the *next* stage, each of the members of $x$ would be a type-$n$ set for some $n$ (but not necessarily the same $n$ for each member of $x).$  So now we get infinite sets like $\lbrace \emptyset,
\lbrace \emptyset \rbrace,
\lbrace \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace\rbrace,
\lbrace \lbrace \lbrace \emptyset\rbrace\rbrace\rbrace, \dots \rbrace.$

Just to give it a name, the new stage is stage $\omega.$  But that's not enough — if $A$ is that infinite set we constructed, we don't have $\lbrace A \rbrace$ yet, for example.  That will come, along with many other sets, at the next stage, which is stage $\omega+1.$ All the members of stage-$(\omega+1)$ sets are of type $\alpha$ for some $\alpha\le\omega.$ Of course, that's not enough either: $\lbrace \lbrace A \rbrace \rbrace$ is constructed at stage $\omega+2,$ $\lbrace\lbrace \lbrace A \rbrace \rbrace\rbrace$ comes at stage $\omega+3,$ etc.

After all these stages comes stage $\omega+\omega,$ also called stage $\omega 2.$ An example of a new set we get here is  $\lbrace A,
\lbrace A \rbrace,
\lbrace \lbrace A \rbrace\rbrace,
\lbrace \lbrace \lbrace A\rbrace\rbrace\rbrace, \dots \rbrace.$

And we can keep on going.  After stages $\omega 2+n$ for all natural numbers $n,$ we'll get stage $\omega+\omega+\omega,$ also called stage $\omega 3.$  Keep on going for a while and you'll eventually reach stages $\omega 4, \omega 5, \omega 5,$ etc.  But we're not done yet: next come stages $\omega \omega,$ also called stage $\omega^2.$  Then come stages $\omega \omega + 1,  \omega \omega + 2, \dots.$  Eventually we'll reach stage $\omega \omega \omega,$ also called stage $\omega^3.$ And after going through the same sort of steps infinitely many times, stage $\omega^4,$ and so on.  Then we get stages $\omega^5, \omega^6, \omega^7,$ etc.  But we can't be done yet.  Next comes stage $\omega^\omega,$ and so on and so on.  Forever.

What does "forever" mean?  This can't be fully characterized (in first-order logic anyway).  After all, if you've characterized what you think it means, you can add a stage allowing you to collect sets from all the previous stages, and so start going on even farther.

But there is one thing that we know about the stages: they're well-ordered.  You can see that from the construction, which is indexed by what will turn out to be ordinal numbers.  If some set is constructed, then it's supposed to be constructed for the *first* time at some particular stage, so it isn't constructed in any earlier stage.  This is the entire conception of the construction: each set has as its elements only already-constructed members of *previous* stages.

And now that we finally have a fairly good picture of how the universe of sets is constructed, we finally get to the well-foundedness of the $\in$ relation.  If $X$ is any non-empty set, look at the members of $X.$  These members of $X$ are constructed at various stages.  Look at the *first* stage $s$ at which a member of $X$ appears.  (There must be such a first stage because the stages are well-ordered.)  If $a$ is any member of $X$ that appears at stage $s,$ then none of the members of $a$ can also belong to $X$ (since any member of $a$ must come from some stage prior to $s,$ but $s$ is the earliest stage at which a member of $X$ appears).  So $X$ has a member $a$ such that $X\cap a=\emptyset.$  And this is what motivates the axiom of foundation and $\in$-induction.

The axioms of ZF are an attempt to formalize the ideas above. You start with the empty set.  You can form the power set of any set and then carve out subsets of that, letting you go from one stage to the next.  The axiom of infinity ensures that stage $\omega$ exists, and the axiom of replacement is an attempt at saying the whole process goes on forever.  (And large cardinal axioms are added as ways of saying that the stages go on even farther.  ZF, or ZF with some large cardinal axiom, provides one of the natural stopping points I alluded to above.)

Comment: I disagree that excluding ill-founded sets is how Russell's paradox is resolved - the only way to resolve Russell is to substantially weaken the comprehension. Indeed, there are consistent set theories with ill-founded sets, such as $NFU$ or $ZF^-+AFS$, and *adding* axioms (like foundation) never makes a theory *more* consistent.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I agree that this isn't the *only* way to resolve Russell's paradox, but the cumulative hierarchy, constructed in well-ordered stages, is the approach that has been settled on as the *standard* way of doing so.  Moreover, the OP's question was: Why is $\in$ well-founded? I think the correct answer historically is that it is part of a solution to Russell's paradox, and that solution was so successful that it has been canonized as the standard approach .

Comment: I realize that, but my point is that the cumulative hierarchy is *not* part of a solution to Russell's paradox! Rather, it is a natural theory of sets, with good intuitive foundation, *compatible with the restrictions required* to avoid Russell's paradox! That is, the cumulative hierarchy gives an intuitive justification for excluding full comprehension, but the solution to Russell's paradox is that exclusion itself rather than the cumulative hierarchy construction.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It's not merely compatible: Russell introduced his theory of types precisely to address the paradox, and the cumulative hierarchy of sets is the natural extension of Russell's type theory into the transfinite.  So the well-ordered cumulative hierarchy is directly motivated historically by the issue of Russell's paradox.